# symfony redirect with 2 parameters

Tags: php, redirect, symfony1

How can I redirect to another action passing 2 or more parameters?

This code:

```
$this->redirect('input/new?year=' . $year . '&month=' . $month);
```

Results in URL:

`http://.../input?year=2009&amp;month=9`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Well, that's normal, "redirect" redirect to an absolute URL. You can do that:

```
$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('default', array('module' => 'input',
'action' => 'new', 'year' => $year, 'month' => $month)));
```

Comment: that helped. except for it generates url like "http://.../input/new/year/2009/month/10"

Comment: If you have a route defined, you can replace 'default' by its name, and change the second parameter with the routes's parameters, if needed.

Comment: If you have a route defined, you can actually use `$this->redirectToRoute('routename', ['param1' => 'value', ['param2' => 'value'])`

Answer (score 11):

In the currently supported Symfony versions (2.7+) [it's even easier](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#redirecting) (plus, you can optionally add also the status code at the end):

```
return $this->redirectToRoute(
    'default',
    array('year' => $year, 'month' => $month),
    Response::HTTP_MOVED_PERMANENTLY // = 301
);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use redirect, specifying the route name and the parameter array:

```
$this->redirect('route_name', array('year' => $year, 'month' => $month));
```

(Tested on Symfony 1.4)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is no normal symfony behavior. Have you defined some routing rules?

Have you also tried this:

```
$this->redirect('module/action?'.http_build_query($paramsArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

Strange thing. Does

```
$this->redirect('@default?module=input&action=new&year=' . $year . '&month=' . $month);
```

work for you?

Comment: yes, that also work. thanks, but xarch's solution is prettier =)

Answer (score -3):

```
$this->redirect('input/new/year/' . $year . '/month/' . $month);
```

Comment: this undermine the internal routing system of symfony

Comment: it actually doesn't. symfony's intelligent internal routing engine is exactly why this redirect works! but thanks for the down vote ;)

Comment: when you do it this way you have to change all links/redirects when adjusting the according routing rule