# Symfony routing to external site including session value

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm porting a legacy system that uses Symfony framework. I have almost no experience on Symfony at all.

I need to overwrite a route to an action to an external site and including a session value as a parameter.

This is the current `routing.yml` code

```
mysystemtool:
  url:   /:module/mysystemtool/tool/*
  param: { action: mysystemtool }
```

And I need to redirect to a url like `http://thirdpartyurl.com/?session_param=session_value`

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Which Symfony version? Legacy suggests 1.x, however, it's always more safe you name it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Routing is for mapping incoming URI's to a controller/action. If you need to generate external URL's then you'll need your own logic/methods as this is outside the scope of the routing component.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cant route it perse becuase routing is only for internal stuff. That said you can redirect in the controller:

```
public function executeMysystemtool(sfWebRequest $request) {

    $param = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('session_param', 'default_value');
    $this->redirect('http://thirdpartyurl.com?session_param='.$param);
}
```

Of course you need your `actions.class.php` set up in a module so that you can code this action but if its an existing action then you should just have to change the logic in the action.

Comment: The brilliant thing about this is that it also works for internal stuff when you don't want Symfony to mess with the URL. For instance in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496975/symfony-redirect-with-2-parameters if you don't want all GET parameters to be /stacked/into/slashes/like/that

Comment: @user14764: Well in that case you can also change the routing rules to append extra parameters as a query string :-)