# Symfony Routing __isInitialized__

Tags: php, symfony

When my controller code below is executed, the routing shows `__isInitialized__`. I have no idea why this could happen.

Expected result : `.....?city=1`

Current result : `....?city[__isInitialized__]=1`

Controller

```
if ($form->get('saveAndAdd')->isClicked()) {
    return $this->redirectToRoute('create_post', array('city' => 1));
}
```

Route

```
create_post:
    path: /create
    defaults:
        _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:create
```

Comment: Please show us the route definition.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496975/symfony-redirect-with-2-parameters

Comment: `__isInitialized__` is Doctrine's stuff, not Symfony's itself. So I don't think that the provided code is the one that you're running.